# Requisições Ajax não param de carregar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Eu estou com este problema já a muitos dias, estou com uma página onde carrega externamente o link de uma câmera de segurança para exibir a imagem na página principal, até ai tudo bem, a imagem mostra normalmente na minha página, porém, todas as requisições XHR não funcionam, elas ficam no status "pending" o tempo inteiro, provavelmente é porquê o link da câmera nunca termina de carregar e então as requisições esperam ela terminar?, como posso contornar o problema?, aqui é como eu estou chamando o vídeo, que inclusive roda na página normalmente:

```
<div id="player">
   <img src="/link-da-camera-aqui" height="420" />
</div>';
```

Depois eu tento fazer as requisições para verificar se tem alguma nova mensagem na página, é essa requisição que nunca termina de carregar:

```
    setInterval(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/verifica-novas-mensagens", success: function(resultado){
        if(resultado === '0'){
        alert('Erro na transmissão do vídeo');
        location.href="/home";
        }
        document.getElementById("novas-mensagens").innerHTML = resultado + "<br>";
        }});
    }, 8000);
```

A imagem da câmera funciona normalmente sem travar, mas o link dela nunca termina de carregar e infelizmente nenhum `XHR` funciona, obrigado desde já!

Comment: na url, coloque o nome do arquivo a qual deseja

Comment: Eu estou utilizando url amigável, no caso elas direcionam já para o arquivo, eu tentei colocar o arquivo direto também mas não funcionou

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer a requisição em background para não parar os outros processos, colocando o async : true, eu não sei o porque você esta utilizando o setInterval, se for possível remova-o:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    async : true,
    url: "/verifica-novas-mensagens", success: function(resultado){
    if(resultado === '0'){
    alert('Erro na transmissão do vídeo');
    location.href="/home";
    }
    document.getElementById("novas-mensagens").innerHTML = resultado + "<br>";
}});
```

Comment: Oi Wictor, eu preciso verificar isso de tempos em tempos, no caso eu estava verificando de 8 em 8 segundos, a intenção é mostrar as mensagens novas para o usuário sem precisar dar um refresh sempre, neste seu método o script funcionou, mas preciso executá-lo sempre na página

Comment: " mas preciso executá-lo sempre na página", não entendi esta parte

Comment: Quis dizer que no caso preciso ficar enviando esta requisição em um certo intervalo de tempo para trazer as mensagens em "tempo real", sempre verificando se alguma mensagem nova chegou